# jQuery cancel previously queued event handlers to restart CSS animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, event-handling, css-animations

I'm creating a slideshow, which will run on a timer (shown by progress bar), but allow users to click arrows to force next. I'm trying to use as much CSS3 as possible, so for my loop timer I'm using the CSS3 animation of the progress bar.

The way it works is that I start my progress bar at `width:0`, and set it to `width:100%;`. It has a CSS3 `transition` of `5s`. I then watch for the end of the animation, and use that to call my `resetprogress` and `changeimage` functions, after which I then start the progress again. It loops indefinitely.

I've created a jsFiddle, simplified, to show what I'm talking about: **http://jsfiddle.net/a3H9L/**

Code for the simplified version is below. As you can see, I call `startProgress`, in which I start the CSS3 animation by changing the width, then set a watcher for the end of said animation, at which point I reset and then start again.

```
startProgress();

function startProgress() {
    $('div').width('100%');
    $('div').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',function(e){
        resetProgress();
        startProgress();
    });
}

function resetProgress (){
    $('div').addClass('notransition'); // Disable transitions
    $('div').width('0');
    $('div')[0].offsetHeight; // Trigger a reflow, flushing the CSS changes
    $('div').removeClass('notransition'); // Re-enable transitions
}

$('button').click(function(event){
    resetProgress();
    startProgress();
});
```

My question is, if a user clicks the reset (which will eventually be Next and Previous), how do I break the original loop before resetting and starting a new loop? Right now, I think that I'm starting a new loop without ending the original, which is getting me two loops running at the same time.

EDIT: The reason I think something is wrong is that as I clicked reset a few times, things in the loop start happening at other times besides when the progress is reset.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but do you mean you're worried you're ending up with lots of event handlers and you're looking to clear them? AFAI can see you don't actually need to add and remove the handlers all the time, if you need to "disable" them, use a shared flag instead

Comment: I'm just wondering if I'm getting extra loops that are all concurrently running, and if so how do I break the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Simply call an `.off()` before chaining your `.one()`

---

*Let's run an experiment using your fiddle.*

**Experiment 1:**

Using the console to log a simple message everytime the `.one()` function is called:

```
$('div').one('...', function(e) {
    console.log('one called!');
    resetProgress();
    startProgress();
});
```

**Observation:**

Yes, you are right, they do stack! If you click on the button, more `.one()` functions are added and will fire together at the same time once the bar reaches the end of the animation. ALL of them will still fire once the animation completes the following and subsequent times!

i.e.: Run fiddle, click your button five times. On completion of the first animation, console logs six messages (5 + 1). The bar resets itself and produces another six more messages. This goes on in multiples of six.

---

**Experiment 2:**

Now, let's try turning itself off at the start of the function:

```
$('div').one('...', function(e) {
    $(this).off(e);
    console.log('one called!');
    resetProgress();
    startProgress();
});
```

**Observation:**

This didn't produce the cancelling effect we were expecting. Same result as the first experiment.

---

**Experiment 3:**

Let's try turning all the handlers off (by omitting the "e"):

```
$('div').one('...', function(e) {
    $(this).off();
    console.log('one called!');
    resetProgress();
    startProgress();
});
```

**Observation:**

All queued `.one()` handlers execute at the end of the animation, but they terminate themselves after running once and do not fire the next time the animation completes.

---

**Experiment 4:**

What you actually wanted to do, was to cancel all previously queued handlers before setting a new one. So let's do this:

```
$('div').off().one('...', function(e) {
    console.log('one called!');
    resetProgress();
    startProgress();
});
```

**Observation:**

There's your answer! This function now runs once, as the previous handlers were unset before a new one has been placed. Simply call an `.off()` before chaining your `.one()`

---

*Disclaimer:*

These experiments assume that those were your only event handlers on your element. If you have additional handlers set by `.on()`, `.one()` or similar, instead of using `.off()` to clear everything, you have to specify which handlers you want to clear, like so:

```
.off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend')
```

Comment: Wow, A for effort, I really appreciate it! That last one does seem to solve the issue, thank you!

Comment: Mhm, gotta be careful there. Thing is, I just realized something. I'm making this way too difficult. I can instead just change the `.one` to a `.on` and pull it out of the repeating function. In which case it doesn't need the `.off`. I just tried it, and it achieves the same result! Huzzah!